# Integrate Active Directory Authentication for OSX development (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, authentication, active-directory

I am developing an application for my company and I would like to integrate Active Directory(AD) so that uses can be authenticated through their AD credentials.

My question is, are there any frameworks, APIs, or SDKs that would enable me to integrate AD into my OSX application, preferably in swift?

I have looked into the [Microsoft Azure Framework](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) on GitHub but that work because as I've been told, Microsoft Azure is not compatible with the regular Active Directory.

I have look on the Microsoft Developer Network and have found mention of ["Active Directory Service Interfaces"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170(v=vs.85).aspx) but have not been able to find anything to help me connect to AD.

I've also signed up for Auth0 but the feature I need (Authentication through Active Directory) is quite expensive for what we are doing.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this in the end? I'm having the same issues you had. I need to integrate AD B2C to my swift app but apparently all the documentation is in obj C so far.

Comment: So I was finally able to find a solution to this problem. I talked with a few of the web developers on my team, and they were able to find a [node module](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) that they set up and REST API endpoint with. From this point, all I had to do was hit it with GET request with the username and password as parameters and got back a success or failure message. Hope this helps.